# Array with php for Json output

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, json, google-analytics

i'm trying to get the best practice to manipulate my array to get a json in a format similar to this one (better to work with charts)

```
   {
    "serieMonth":["Aug-12","Sep-12","Oct-12","Nov-12","Dec-12","Jan-13","Feb-13"],
    "serieCA":[4214,10119,13325,12818,7177,20628,7664],
    "serieAdwordsCA":[0,0,0,0,0,310,332],
    "serieBooking":[10,28,46,34,17,51,16],
    "serieAdwords":[0,0,0,0,0,1,1],
    "serieTotalBooking":[10,28,46,34,17,52,17],
    "serieCartRepartition":[421,361,290,377,422,397,451],
    "serieTotalCart":[421,361,290,377,422,397,451]
    }
```

Actually my output looks like this :

```
[
{"date_year":"2012","date_month":"08","ad_cost":"0.0","ad_clicks":"0"},
{"date_year":"2012","date_month":"09","ad_cost":"0.0","ad_clicks":"0"},
{"date_year":"2012","date_month":"10","ad_cost":"0.0","ad_clicks":"0"},
{"date_year":"2012","date_month":"11","ad_cost":"0.0","ad_clicks":"0"},
{"date_year":"2012","date_month":"12","ad_cost":"44.9","ad_clicks":"43"},
{"date_year":"2013","date_month":"01","ad_cost":"297.56","ad_clicks":"462"},
{"date_year":"2013","date_month":"02","ad_cost":"82.5","ad_clicks":"103"}
]
```

And I'm using javascript to change it :

```
var xAxisLabels = new Array(),
adClicks = new Array(),
adCost = new Array();
$.each(data, function(i,v) {
  xAxisLabels.push(v["date_month"]+'/'+v["date_year"]);
  adCost.push(parseInt(v["ad_cost"]));
  adClicks.push(parseInt(v["ad_clicks"]));
});
```

I'm looking for the best way to do it in php since I get this data by the google api, here is my php.

```
// dimensions
$dimensions = 'ga:year,ga:month';
$_params[] = 'date_year';
$_params[] = 'date_month';
// metrics
$metrics = 'ga:adCost,ga:adClicks';
$_params[] = 'ad_cost';
$_params[] = 'ad_clicks';

$response = $service->data_ga->get('ga:' . $projectId, $from, $to, $metrics, array('dimensions' => $dimensions));

$analyticsStats = array();
foreach ($response['rows'] as $row) {
  $dataRow = array();
  foreach ($_params as $colNr => $column) {
    $dataRow[$column] = $row[$colNr];
  }
  array_push($analyticsStats, $dataRow);
}
```

Comment: The "output" does not seem to contain all values required to build the "input".

Comment: Yeah the output is an exemple for the format I would like to get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build an array of arrays then add items the the sub-arrays in a loop:

```
$output = array(
    "serieMonth" => array(),
    "serieCA" => array(),
    "serieAdwordsCA" => array(),
    "serieBooking" => array(),
    "serieAdwords" => array(),
    "serieTotalBooking" => array(),
    "serieCartRepartition" => array(),
    "serieTotalCart" => array()
);
foreach($response["rows"] as $row) {
    $output["serieMonth"][] = date("Y-M", strtotime("{$row['date_year']}-{$row['date_month']}-01"));
    $output["serieCA"][] = $row["ad_cost"];
    $output["serieAdwordsCA"][] = $row["ad_clicks"];
    // etc...
}
echo json_encode($output);
```